# How to close Dialog that uses AbstractDialogAction

Tags: netbeans, dialog, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on Netbeans building a JavaFX application.
I started using `ControlsFX` (http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)
I have implemented a simple `Dialog` that uses custom `AbstractDialogAction` s as I want specific number of buttons to appear.
*I do this like this*:

```
    Action a = new AbstractDialogAction("  button a  ", Dialog.ActionTrait.CLOSING) {
        @Override
        public void execute(ActionEvent ae) {
        }
    };
    ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
    actions.add(a);
    actions.add(b); // other button
    actions.add(c); // another button
    dialog.actions(actions);
    Action response =  dialog.showConfirm();
```

`Dialog` is shown correctly with the given buttons.
My question is how to force the `Dialog` to close when a button is pressed ?
I thought setting a Dialog.ActionTrait.CLOSING would do the trick, but the Dialog stays open.

Comment: See my answer on `ControlsFX` mailing list.

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov Questions on SO are meant to be answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [eugener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112877/eugener) in ControlsFX mailing list

```
public void execute(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() instanceof Dialog ) {
          ((Dialog) ae.getSource()).setResult(this);
       }
}
```

The above sets the result of the `Dialog` to be the current `Action` and closes the `Dialog`
But maybe that is a little redundant as I can simply call:

```
          ((Dialog) ae.getSource()).hide();
```

`.hide()` hides the `Dialog` and also sets the current action as the result.
I can't suggest which is a better solution (`hide()` was suggested by [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea))
In addition I would suggest to always override the `toString()` method of class `AbstractDialogAction`, in order to get readable result from:

```
Action response =  dialog.showConfirm();
System.out.println("RESPONSE = "+ response.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the dialog to close it => [dialog.hide()](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialog.html#hide--)